# issue in converting the date from string to date type

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

below is the code I have used to add the number of days to the existing date..which gave me string output and I want that to be converted to Date format again...I have tried formating but it gave the out put -->

Date date = sdf.parse(dt);
sysout (date )   --giving me -- Mon May 05 00:00:00 PDT 2008
but I want it as YYYY-MM/DD

sdf.format(date)  --Gives me 2008-05-05 which I am looking but it is a string object...but I want this to be converted to DATE type

```
    String dt = "2008-01-01";  // Start date
    System.out.println("start date "+dt);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 125);  // number of days to add
    dt = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    System.out.println("c.getTime() "+c.getTime());
    System.out.println("end date "+dt);

     Date date = sdf.parse(dt);
    System.out.println("last but one date in DATE form -->" +date);
     System.out.println("last formatted date in string form "+sdf.format(date));
```

Comment: `java.util.Date` doesn't have a format you can override. For your desired output, `System.out.println("last but one date -->" + sdf.format(date));`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch OP just parsed the `date` from string variable `dt`. why would he want to format it to a string again?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh OP is expecting `date` to persist format; *I have tried formatting it but it outputs: "last but one date -->Mon May 05 00:00:00 PDT 2008"; I want it in yyyy-MM-dd format*. Or so I interpret the question.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ..have done that in my last logger..which I missed in my post..now I added it...but it give me the result as  Mon May 05 00:00:00 PDT 2008

Comment: yes Gurwinder...I missed that line in my post..Now I have added..

Comment: @javalearner What is your question exactly? Please edit the question to include ***both*** your current output **and** your desired output.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch modified the question...pls let me know if you need any further details

Comment: A `Date` is a number of milliseconds from epoch (January 1, 1970 at midnight UTC). You cannot change the default `toString` of `Date`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130751/discussion-between-javalearner-and-elliott-frisch).

Answer (score 0):

You created the format right.
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

but you are using it incorrectly. you should use 
sdf.format(your_unformated_date);

Comment: have done that in last sysout..which  I missed in my post..now I added it..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that will convert date from String to Date type using SimpleDateFormat Class:

```
public static void convert()
{
     String str="10:25:35";
     SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
     System.out.println(sdf.format(str));
 }
```